# Resize a ListItem to the size of the ListItemText so simulate Chat bubbles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is my current state:

[image]

and my Code:

```js
<ListItem
  sx={{
    textAlign: "left",
    bgcolor: "#f6f6f6",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    marginBottom: "1rem",
  }}
>
  <ListItemText
    sx={{ textAlign: "right" }}
    primary={
      <React.Fragment>
        <Typography sx={{ textAlign: "right" }} color="text.primary">
          {" "}
          {" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"}
        </Typography>
      </React.Fragment>
    }
    secondary={
      <React.Fragment>
        <Typography
          sx={{
            fontWeight: "bold",
            fontSize: "12px",
            textAlign: "right",
            marginTop: 1,
          }}
          color="text.primary"
        >
          {" "}
          {"22:44"}
        </Typography>
      </React.Fragment>
    }
  />
  <ListItemAvatar sx={{ ml: 2, textAlign: "right" }}>
    <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src={w1} />
  </ListItemAvatar>
</ListItem>
```

I want to resize the width of the white container (marked in a red border) to the size of the text of the "Typography" in my "primary" in "ListItemText". I tried to figure it out by inspecting the css but was not able to do it.

How can I resize the bubble according to my text value to make it look like a "chat bubble"?

Answer (score 0):

On the `ListItem` we can add the following styles to the `sx` prop:

- `width: "fit-content"` to make the width fit the content instead of using all available width
- `marginLeft: "auto"` this will make sure the message stays on the right

```js
<ListItem
  sx={{
    textAlign: "left",
    bgcolor: "#f6f6f6",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    marginBottom: "1rem",
    width: "fit-content",
    marginLeft: "auto",
  }}
>
  ...
</ListItem>
```

**Note** that the `marginLeft: "auto"` only applies for items on the right. If you want to have the same for the left items (blue) you can use `marginRight: "auto"`

See here for a [live preview](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-jones-0t8ktu?file=/demo.tsx)